# Cassandra java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on CentOS 7

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Hello I am getting this error while starting Cassandra and after 2-3 minutes I get this message

```
WARN  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,826 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 23493ms.  CMS Old Gen: 9898557408 -> 9898557384; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 671088632; Par Survivor Space: 83886056 -> 80972352
INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,827 StatusLogger.java:47 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,834 StatusLogger.java:51 - MutationStage                     1         0         854699         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,836 StatusLogger.java:51 - ViewMutationStage                 0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,838 StatusLogger.java:51 - ReadStage                         0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:28,839 StatusLogger.java:51 - RequestResponseStage              0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,452 StatusLogger.java:51 - ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,453 StatusLogger.java:51 - CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,454 StatusLogger.java:51 - MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,454 StatusLogger.java:51 - CompactionExecutor                0         0             26         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,455 StatusLogger.java:51 - MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0             23         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,455 StatusLogger.java:51 - GossipStage                       0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,456 StatusLogger.java:51 - SecondaryIndexManagement          0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:17:45,457 StatusLogger.java:51 - HintsDispatcher                   0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:18:05,523 StatusLogger.java:51 - MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:18:05,524 StatusLogger.java:51 - MemtablePostFlush                 0         0             23         0                 0

INFO  [Service Thread] 2021-10-19 13:18:22,163 StatusLogger.java:51 - PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0         0         0             23         0                 0

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid40352.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [17225711047 bytes in 125.079 secs]


# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 40352"...
```

I tried various combinations of Heap sizes. tried increasing it up to 16GB, still not working.
Any help will me much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, faced this issue sometime back. Can you check your compaction throughput?
use - nodetool getcompactionthroughput